# Finding events that two different members both participated in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, pdo

In a system, there are `Events`, `EventRosters`, `Teams`, `TeamRosters`, `Members`, and `Gamertags`.

`Events`: Video game events, can be solo (1v1) or team (team vs team) (Example columns: id, type(solo/team), participants, starting time, prize, etc).

`EvenRosters`: Roster of gamertags playing in this event regardless if it's a team or solo event (if team event, team!=0) (Example columns: id,event,gamertag,team)

`Teams`: Table consisting of team data (Example columns: id, team name, created date, public/private, icon file name, etc)

`TeamRosters`: Table consisting of member IDs belonging to said team (Example columns: id, team, member)

`Members`: Table consisting of member data (Example columns: id, email, username, etc)

`Gamertags`: Table consisting of gamertags (for xbox, playstation, etc) belonging to members (Example columns: id, gamertag, member)

For a solo event:

`Events`:

- ID = [Auto Increment]
- Type = 0 (0 = solo, 1 = team)
- Challenger = Challenger_Member_ID (participant 1)
- Contestant = Contestant_Member_ID (participant 2)
- Starting time = time()
- Prize = 40 ($40USD)

`EventRosters`:

- ID = [Auto Increment]
- Team = 0 (0 = solo roster)
- Gamertag = Challenger_Gamertag_ID
- Event = Event_ID

Then for a team event:

`Events`:

- ID = [Auto Increment]
- Type = 1 (0 = solo, 1 = team)
- Challenger = Challenger_Team_ID (participant 1)
- Contestant = Contestant_Team_ID (participant 2)
- Starting time = time()
- Prize = 100($100USD)

`EventRosters`:

- ID = [Auto Increment]
- Team = Challenger_Team_ID (0 = solo roster)
- Gamertag = Challenger_Team_Participant_Gamertag_ID
- Event = Event_ID

So, fetching solo events are simple enough because the `Member_ID` is available directly from the `Event.Challenger` or `Event.Contestant` columns. However, if we want to know member names of those who participated in a team event, or if we want to search team events that a certain member participated in, we have a few choices.

Question: Is it possible to fetch this data in a single query?

**Purpose: Find team events that two different specified members both participated in**

```
METHOD 1 : START WITH MEMBER GAMERTAGS
// Fetch team events that two different members both participated in.
$memberID = 3;
$secondMemberID = 5;

$memberGamertags = $pdo->Query('SELECT id FROM member_gamertags WHERE member='.$memberID);
$st = $pdo->Prepare('SELECT event,team FROM event_rosters WHERE team=0 AND gamertag=?');
foreach($memberGamertags as $gt) {
  $st->Execute([$gt['id']]);
  $rosterFile = $st->Fetch();
  $event = $pdo->Query('SELECT id,challenger,contestant FROM events WHERE id='.$rosterFile['event'])->Fetch();
  // check if proper team
  $otherTeamID = ( $event['challenger'] == $rosterFile['team'] ) ? $event['contestant'] : $event['challenger'];
  // now search that team for other member
  $otherTeamRoster = $pdo->Query('SELECT * FROM team_rosters WHERE member='.$secondMemberID.' AND team='.$otherTeamID)->Fetch();
  if ( $otherTeamRoster ) // found an event they both participated in
    $foundEvents[] = $event;
}
//
// REPEAT FOR OTHER MEMBER
//
```

Comment: It most certainly is possible (that's what a database does). But before I look closer at your tables: I'm not sure, but your code looks like you don't know `JOIN`. A join will combine two tables under a given condition. It is probably THE most important concept in a relational database. E.g. for a team event, you would join `events` with `teams` (using the link challenger_id -> teamid ), this again with `teamroaster` (using the link id->team) and this again with `member`. Your datamodel is a bit wrong too (making it more complicated than needed), but `join` might be the missing piece here.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of JOIN but I only know very basic use with it. Just got acquainted with more complex examples a short while ago.

Comment: Maybe some links on 'join': general concept: [Understanding JOINs in MySQL and Other Relational Databases](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/), more focus on php-focus: [Using MySQL Joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: Well, if you have a specific search you want to try, I could give you the code with a join so you could play with it, but maybe you should not start with joins over 4 tables (it is of course possible though). Joins are really really powerful once you get used to it. (Unfortunately, your database design makes it a little bit harder for you, because in the "Challenger" and "Contestant"-fields you mix Memberids and Teamids, but that is a minor problem). So as I said, if you want to see some select (maybe one that you have already done with php loops), I could give you a translation with join.

Comment: You're right, it would be more efficient to setup team-challenger and solo-challenger and only fill out one depending on the match type. But in the mean time, could you show me an example searching for two member IDs, say, 1 and 2?

Comment: Without guarantees: `select ev.id,ev.challenger,ev.contestant
from event_rosters evr1 
join member_gamertags gt1
on gt1.id = evr1.gamertag
join events ev
on ev.id = evr1.event
join team_rosters tr1
on (tr2.team = ev.challenger or tr2.team = ev.contestant) and (tr2.team <> er1.team)
where evr1.team = 0 
and gt1.member = $memberID
and tr2.member = $secondMemberID;`
I didn't check it against your tables (would take some time to go through them), but this should be a 1:1 translation of your php code and give you the same result and maybe an idea about how to use joins. Good luck!